# How could I display a line graph which is linked to a MySQL database?

Tags: javascript

I have never used javascript or jscript and I was wondering how i could display a graph on my website. I have had a look at google charts but that doesnt accomodate for linking too a dataset.

Hope you can help.

Comment: What server-side technology are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mmm... You don't know JS, but you want a JS based solution? Here's a link to flot, a good free charting lib (jquery plugin) that I use: http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/

Here's how to build a simple chart with it, see the linked code[image]

```
// http://people.iola.dk/olau/flot/examples/basic.html
$(function () {
    var d1 = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < 14; i += 0.5)
        d1.push([i, Math.sin(i)]);

    var d2 = [[0, 3], [4, 8], [8, 5], [9, 13]];

    // a null signifies separate line segments
    var d3 = [[0, 12], [7, 12], null, [7, 2.5], [12, 2.5]];

    $.plot($("#placeholder"), [ d1, d2, d3 ]);
});
```

All you need to do is be able to output json arrays from whatever server side language you're using. So in a php file, you could do the following:

```
var d2 = <?= json_encode(array(array(0,3), array(3,5), array(6,7))) ?>
```

Answer (score 2):

take a look at [grapheal.js](http://g.raphaeljs.com/)

This should allow you to nicely draw graphs of data.

The real issue is how to get your data from your mySQL database into the client. This depends on your server side platform.

Either way you should be able to simply use ajax to fetch data and pass it onto grapheal in a format it understands.

Comment: Raphael is a great library. One of the reasons it's better than the one I suggested is the fact that everything on the graph is a node, so you can interact with it (mouseover, click). Canvas based solutions are pixel based and require a lot of custom code to detect that a line is clicked.

Comment: @JuanMendes that's why I fell in love with rapheal. Can treat the entire thing in an OO manner.